# dblib on Mac connects to the logins default database instead of 'dbname'

Tags: php, pdo, freetds

When I connect to a remote SQL Server database from my Mac, using pdo/dblib, the dbname value from the dns string is not used.  Whatever default database is assigned to the login credentials, is set as the context database.

For instance, I create new database called DB1 and a new login name PDO/PDO mapped as the db_owner, leaving the default database set to 'master'.  Then connect to SQL Server as

```
"dblib:host=10.44.68.187;dbname=DB1", "PDO", "PDO"
```

Run the statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT CATALOG_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

and get the result

```
[catalog_name] => master
```

which should be DB1.  I can use the same script, switching to pdo/sqlsrv, on the Win2008/R3 and the correct database is returned.

Is there anything to set on the Mac that will force dblib to use the dbname value in the dns string?

TIA

Test script:

```
<?php
try {
    $d = "dblib"; $h = "host"; $n = "dbname";
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['OS'] ) && preg_match( '/Win/', $_SERVER['OS'] )) 
        { $d = "sqlsrv"; $h = "Server"; $n = "Database"; }
    $pdo = new PDO( "$d:$h=10.44.68.187;$n=DB1", "PDO", "PDO" );
    foreach( $pdo->query( "select distinct catalog_name from information_schema.schemata", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) as $r ) {
        print_r($r);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) { print $e."\n"; }
?>
```

freeTDS log from login to the statement execution request:

```
log.c:190:Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.82
        on 2013-10-10 11:21:52 with debug flags 0x4fff.
iconv.c:197:names for ISO-8859-1: ISO-8859-1
iconv.c:197:names for UTF-8: UTF-8
iconv.c:197:names for UCS-2LE: UCS-2LE
iconv.c:197:names for UCS-2BE: UCS-2BE
iconv.c:363:iconv to convert client-side data to the "ISO-8859-1" character set
iconv.c:516:tds_iconv_info_init: converting "ISO-8859-1"->"UCS-2LE"
iconv.c:516:tds_iconv_info_init: converting "ISO-8859-1"->"UCS-2LE"
net.c:210:Connecting to 10.44.68.187 port 1433 (TDS version 8.0)
net.c:264:tds_open_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"
net.c:303:tds_open_socket() succeeded
util.c:162:Changed query state from DEAD to IDLE
login.c:735:quietly sending TDS 7+ login packet
token.c:312:tds_process_login_tokens()
net.c:592:Received header
0000 04 01 01 85 00 34 01 00-                        |.....4..|

net.c:671:Received packet
0000 e3 1b 00 01 06 6d 00 61-00 73 00 74 00 65 00 72 |.....m.a .s.t.e.r|
0010 00 06 6d 00 61 00 73 00-74 00 65 00 72 00 ab 6c |..m.a.s. t.e.r..l|
0020 00 45 16 00 00 02 00 25-00 43 00 68 00 61 00 6e |.E.....% .C.h.a.n|
0030 00 67 00 65 00 64 00 20-00 64 00 61 00 74 00 61 |.g.e.d.  .d.a.t.a|
0040 00 62 00 61 00 73 00 65-00 20 00 63 00 6f 00 6e |.b.a.s.e . .c.o.n|
0050 00 74 00 65 00 78 00 74-00 20 00 74 00 6f 00 20 |.t.e.x.t . .t.o. |
0060 00 27 00 6d 00 61 00 73-00 74 00 65 00 72 00 27 |.'.m.a.s .t.e.r.'|
0070 00 2e 00 0b 49 00 4e 00-46 00 4f 00 52 00 31 00 |....I.N. F.O.R.1.|
0080 30 00 2d 00 49 00 4d 00-53 00 00 01 00 e3 08 00 |0.-.I.M. S.......|
0090 07 05 09 04 d0 00 34 00-e3 17 00 02 0a 75 00 73 |......4. .....u.s|
00a0 00 5f 00 65 00 6e 00 67-00 6c 00 69 00 73 00 68 |._.e.n.g .l.i.s.h|
00b0 00 00 ab 70 00 47 16 00-00 01 00 27 00 43 00 68 |...p.G.. ...'.C.h|
00c0 00 61 00 6e 00 67 00 65-00 64 00 20 00 6c 00 61 |.a.n.g.e .d. .l.a|
00d0 00 6e 00 67 00 75 00 61-00 67 00 65 00 20 00 73 |.n.g.u.a .g.e. .s|
00e0 00 65 00 74 00 74 00 69-00 6e 00 67 00 20 00 74 |.e.t.t.i .n.g. .t|
00f0 00 6f 00 20 00 75 00 73-00 5f 00 65 00 6e 00 67 |.o. .u.s ._.e.n.g|
0100 00 6c 00 69 00 73 00 68-00 2e 00 0b 49 00 4e 00 |.l.i.s.h ....I.N.|
0110 46 00 4f 00 52 00 31 00-30 00 2d 00 49 00 4d 00 |F.O.R.1. 0.-.I.M.|
0120 53 00 00 01 00 ad 36 00-01 71 00 00 01 16 4d 00 |S.....6. .q....M.|
0130 69 00 63 00 72 00 6f 00-73 00 6f 00 66 00 74 00 |i.c.r.o. s.o.f.t.|
0140 20 00 53 00 51 00 4c 00-20 00 53 00 65 00 72 00 | .S.Q.L.  .S.e.r.|
0150 76 00 65 00 72 00 00 00-00 00 0b 00 0c 38 e3 13 |v.e.r... .....8..|
0160 00 04 04 34 00 30 00 39-00 36 00 04 34 00 30 00 |...4.0.9 .6..4.0.|
0170 39 00 36 00 fd 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00          |9.6..... .....|

token.c:316:looking for login token, got  e3(ENVCHANGE)
token.c:108:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is e3(ENVCHANGE)
dblib.c:325:db_env_chg(0x7fefe99cd960, 1, master, master)
token.c:316:looking for login token, got  ab(INFO)
token.c:108:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is ab(INFO)
token.c:2451:tds_process_msg() reading message from server
token.c:2516:tds_process_msg() calling client msg handler
dbutil.c:86:_dblib_handle_info_message(0x7fefe997cb30, 0x7fefe99cd960, 0x7fff5f597140)
dbutil.c:87:msgno 5701: "Changed database context to 'master'."
token.c:2529:tds_process_msg() returning TDS_SUCCEED
token.c:316:looking for login token, got  e3(ENVCHANGE)
token.c:108:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is e3(ENVCHANGE)
token.c:2281:tds_process_env_chg(): 5 bytes of collation data received
token.c:2282:tds->collation was
0000 00 00 00 00 00         -                        |.....|

iconv.c:985:setting server single-byte charset to "CP1252"
iconv.c:516:tds_iconv_info_init: converting "ISO-8859-1"->"CP1252"
token.c:2292:tds->collation now
0000 09 04 d0 00 34         -                        |....4|

token.c:316:looking for login token, got  e3(ENVCHANGE)
token.c:108:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is e3(ENVCHANGE)
dblib.c:325:db_env_chg(0x7fefe99cd960, 2, , us_english)
token.c:316:looking for login token, got  ab(INFO)
token.c:108:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is ab(INFO)
token.c:2451:tds_process_msg() reading message from server
token.c:2516:tds_process_msg() calling client msg handler
dbutil.c:86:_dblib_handle_info_message(0x7fefe997cb30, 0x7fefe99cd960, 0x7fff5f597140)
dbutil.c:87:msgno 5703: "Changed language setting to us_english."
token.c:2529:tds_process_msg() returning TDS_SUCCEED
token.c:316:looking for login token, got  ad(LOGINACK)
token.c:316:looking for login token, got  e3(ENVCHANGE)
token.c:108:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is e3(ENVCHANGE)
dblib.c:325:db_env_chg(0x7fefe99cd960, 4, 4096, 4096)
token.c:316:looking for login token, got  fd(DONE)
token.c:108:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is fd(DONE)
token.c:2201:tds_process_end: more_results = 0
                was_cancelled = 0
                error = 0
                done_count_valid = 0
token.c:2217:tds_process_end() state set to TDS_IDLE
token.c:2232:                rows_affected = 0
token.c:393:leaving tds_process_login_tokens() returning 1
mem.c:563:tds_free_all_results()
util.c:162:Changed query state from IDLE to QUERYING
write.c:136:tds_put_string converting 16 bytes of "set textsize -1 "
write.c:164:tds_put_string wrote 32 bytes
util.c:162:Changed query state from QUERYING to PENDING
net.c:779:Sending packet
0000 01 01 00 28 00 00 00 00-73 00 65 00 74 00 20 00 |...(.... s.e.t. .|
0010 74 00 65 00 78 00 74 00-73 00 69 00 7a 00 65 00 |t.e.x.t. s.i.z.e.|
0020 20 00 2d 00 31 00 20 00-                        | .-.1. .|

token.c:495:tds_process_tokens(0x7fefe99cd960, 0x7fff5f597234, 0x7fff5f597230, 0x100)
util.c:162:Changed query state from PENDING to READING
net.c:592:Received header
0000 04 01 00 11 00 34 01 00-                        |.....4..|

net.c:671:Received packet
0000 fd 00 00 be 00 00 00 00-00                      |........ .|

token.c:510:processing result tokens.  marker is  fd(DONE)
token.c:2201:tds_process_end: more_results = 0
                was_cancelled = 0
                error = 0
                done_count_valid = 0
token.c:2217:tds_process_end() state set to TDS_IDLE
util.c:162:Changed query state from READING to IDLE
token.c:2232:                rows_affected = 0
util.c:110:logic error: cannot change query state from IDLE to PENDING
token.c:495:tds_process_tokens(0x7fefe99cd960, 0x7fff5f597234, 0x7fff5f597230, 0x100)
token.c:498:tds_process_tokens() state is COMPLETED
dblib.c:237:dblib_add_connection(0x102df9a00, 0x7fefe99cd960)
dblib.c:4208:dbsetopt(0x7fefe99cd600, 7, 2147483647, -1)
dblib.c:4323:UNIMPLEMENTED dbsetopt(option = 7)
dblib.c:4208:dbsetopt(0x7fefe99cd600, 17, 2147483647, -1)
dblib.c:4323:UNIMPLEMENTED dbsetopt(option = 17)
dblib.c:4208:dbsetopt(0x7fefe99cd600, 35, 1, -1)
dblib.c:5608:dbsetuserdata(0x7fefe99cd600, 0x1017651a0)
dblib.c:3093:dbcancel(0x7fefe99cd600)
query.c:1934:tds_send_cancel: not in_cancel and idle
dblib.c:1243:dbcmd(0x7fefe99cd600, select distinct catalog_name from information_schema.schemata)
```

Comment: Have you checked the case of the database names? Windows isn't case sensitive, Linux is, Mac can be.

Comment: @OddEssay case is OK.  I created database(DB1) and login(PDO) with all caps.

Comment: This happens to me on Ubuntu. Im using pdo dblib and the dbname passed to the dns string is not being used, i've managed to workaround this, setting the default dbname for the user on the sql server.

I don't know if this is a problem with the dblib extension on PHP or  the FreeTDS version i'm using.